# How to Use @defer Directive in GraphQL Federated Application with NestJS

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs, apollo-server, apollo-federation

I am working on a GraphQL federated application using NestJS, and I'm trying to implement the @defer directive to enable partial query execution and improve the performance of my GraphQL API. However, when I attempt to use @defer in my queries, I encounter the following error:

graphql
Copy code
Unknown directive "@defer".
Here's a brief overview of my setup:

- Framework: NestJS
- GraphQL setup: Apollo Federation
- Goal: Implement
  the @defer directive to defer the execution of certain fields in a
  query

Here's a simplified version of how I'm trying to use @defer:

graphql

```
query {
  user(id: "1") {
    id
    name
    expensiveField @defer
  }
}
```

Attempts to Resolve:

I ensured that my Apollo Server supports @defer by checking the version and documentation.
I've looked into the Apollo Server and NestJS documentation for any additional configuration required for @defer to work in a federated setup but found none that specifically addresses my issue.

I tried to find examples of @defer being used in a federated context with NestJS but came up short.

Questions:

Is there a specific setup or configuration required within NestJS or Apollo Federation to enable support for the @defer directive?

Are there any known compatibility issues or additional steps needed to use @defer in a GraphQL federated application with NestJS?

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully implement @defer in my federated GraphQL application with NestJS.

Thank you in advance!